# handle with SomeException is ignored

Tags: haskell, exception, functional-programming

I have a usual haskell code which reads file and handle any exception:

```hs
handle ((\_->return "ERROR") :: SomeException -> IO String) $ readFile "file.txt"
```

When I try to read bad encoded file I always get error:

```
*** Exception: file.txt: hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)
```

and program is not going to enter to the my exception handle function. I also tried to use `IOError` and `IOException` types instead of `SomeException` but it changes nothing.

If I open similar file with by handle and read it with code:

```hs
handle ((\_->return "ERROR") :: SomeException -> IO String) (hGetContents myHandle)
```

works fine.

How to catch exceptions thrown by `hGetContents` passed by `readFile` right way?

Comment: Isn't there something about `readFile` doing lazy IO - reading the file only after they returned the string? Try forcing the string to be evaluated within the `handle`.

Comment: @Bergi, I run this code in ghci so result is forced immediately

Comment: @Shadasviar That doesn't mean Bergi's diagnosis is wrong, it actually supports the guess.   1. Run readFile, getting some bytes (or perhaps none yet!)  2. Return a (lazy) `String` so now no longer in `handle`.  3. Try to print on the REPL the whole string, thus forcing it all to be read.  4. Encounter error and throw the exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force the entire string to be read within the scope of the catch:

```
Control.Exception.handle
      ((\_ -> return "ERR") :: Control.Exception.SomeException -> IO String)
      (Prelude.readFile "file.txt" >>= \res -> res `deepseq` (pure res))
"ERR"
```